# Bootstrap DateTimePicker inside scrollable modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a bootstrap modal with a body that allows vertical scrolling. Inside of this, I am trying to use a datetime picker, but the problem is that expanding the picker, causes the modal's body to add scroll bars. I need to keep the scrolling ability (for other things that can add content to the modal) but I also need the datetime picker to expand outside of the modal, and not cause the modal to scroll (so that it would occupy the red square without in the pic).

[image]

```
<div class="modal-body" style="overflow-y:scroll;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-4'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id="datetimepicker3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: $data.visitdate" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/axg1010/3xunve7r/

Answer (score 0):

Check out your very first line: `<div class="modal-body" style="overflow-y:scroll;">`. If you take out the `overflow-y:scroll` the calendar will project over your modal.

Comment: I also face same issue, did any one tried with scroll as well ,